# Creating a Counter that increments by 1 every second

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, timer, counter

So I'm trying to make a counter that begins counting as soon as the page is loaded and continues indefinitely. Much like what's done on candies.aniwey.net the only difference is I'm using asp.net and was wondering how to do it and what's the most efficient way? ASP.Net, Javascripting, etc.
Thanks

-- Sorry yeah, in the browser. Should have been more specific.

Comment: Since you have provided only the requirement that something count every second I would say use javascript's setInterval.

Comment: you realize that asp.net is a server-side technology? If you want a clock running on the client-side of things, then you're bound by client-side technologies, which basically means Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the date or datetime class in asp.net (sorry i work java, android, i will use java code)

like java you can use Date class for time operation, like you want to do, for example when the page start loading take a timestamp of the current time, then when the visitor leave take another timestamp,  do the math and voala you have the seconds that person that person stay in that page

in code:

```
Date startTime = new Date();
Date endTime = new Date(); --> this must be activate in a event of some sort
int seconds = endTime - startTime;
```

that is the idea

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want the counting to be done? You say "as soon as the page is loaded" which sounds like you mean in the Browser.

In which case JavaScript.